# how to detect defective CPU

Tags: cpu

I have a few servers with identical hardware, however, a few of them are slower than others. I benchmarked the hardware, with sysbench, the CPU performance for bad servers are also bad. I have no idea why this happens because the hardware and software are all identical (clean system). My only guess is the CPU is defective somehow as they are old.

Is there any way I can detect this?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Not sure whether this topic fits here or not, if not can someone point me to the right place? 
Thank you!

Comment: Check the temperatures of the processors.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you for your suggestion. The temperature is OK, not throttling.

Comment: Why is it downvoted? I can edit it if something is not right.

Comment: Research how overclockers verify their configurations are stable.

Comment: @Ramhound the CPU is not overclocked.

Comment: I understand that, did I say it was, read my comment again please

Comment: @Ramhound sorry about my English, I don't quite catch you, can you explain a little bit? Thank you!

Comment: Intel has an application to burn in a CPU, its used to verify an overclock is stable, the same application can be used to verify your CPU will work.  There are Linux tools that do the samething

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you! i7z show that CPU spends 30% time in C1 state while it is under fullload, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others may find this question useful, I found `turbostat` and `i7z` these two tools, which are useful.